# HTC Desire Z Stock ROM

Tags: htc-desire-z, stock-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Does anybody know how I can find HTC Gingerbread Stock ROM? I've just found an old Froyo (2.2) ROM through google search.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet when looking for ROMs is to [search the XDA subforum for your device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/search.php?searchid=91181260).  Stock 2.3.3 is linked in one of the first few posts there, and I'm sure they'll have instructions if you need them as well.